# How to read the last characters not ending with a newline from a stream

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command-line

I have a script called `test.sh` which processes the standard input line by line like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "start"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "processing[$line]"
done < /dev/stdin
echo "done"
```

The problem with this is, it doesn't process the characters between the last *newline* and the *eof*.

```
printf $'line 1\nline 2\nlast chars' | test.sh
```

will output

```
start
processing[line 1]
processing[line 2]
done
```

The reason I read line by line is that I need to inspect the first line and in some cases I want to remove it from the output stream.

How can I process these last characters? I've looked into `read -n` but then I would need to supply how many characters to expect at a maximum and I rather don't build in limits.

Also: I wouldn't know where to put this statement in the while-loop. I'm on the macOS platform.

Comment: Only `\n` are used.

Comment: To summarize the problem your problem, `read` fails if it doesn't see a newline termination, so for the last line it will return a non-zero exit code, simply add a check as `read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]`

Comment: Ah, `read` **does** read the last chars. I didn't realize this. And a nice solution for the condition; I'd never have thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: One caveat though: you can't distinguish between the two cases, but then I realized the last chars are also available within `$line` after the `while` loop, so I can use `printf` to write the last line without a new line.